# How to obtain a QuerySet of all rows, with specific fields for each one of them?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model `Employees` and I would like to have a QuerySet of all rows, but with some specific fields from each row, and not all fields.

I know how to query all rows from the table/model:

```
Employees.objects.all()
```

I would like to know how to select fields for each of the Queryset element. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "and using only one"? A `SELECT col` instead of `SELECT *`?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

```
Employees.objects.values_list('eng_name', flat=True)
```

That creates a flat list of all `eng_name`s. If you want more than one field per row, you can't do a flat list: this will create a list of tuples:

```
Employees.objects.values_list('eng_name', 'rank')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, what if I want to select only 1 or more fields (not all)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: please share the document.that will helps to others

Comment: Does values_list  return a dictionary similar values or an object?

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'

Answer (score 48):

In addition to `values_list` as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7503368/1523238) you can also use [`only`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) (or [`defer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer) for the opposite effect) to get a queryset of objects only having their id and specified fields:

```
Employees.objects.only('eng_name')
```

This will run a single query:

```
SELECT id, eng_name FROM employees
```

Comment: This command is returning me all the fields for my Django version 2.1.3 and python version 3.6.2.

Comment: It will only fetch this one filed, but if you try to access other fields, a separate database query will be executed.
So this is a good optimization technique, but make sure that you do not create these extra queries. Otherwise you will lose performance instead of gaining it.

Comment: The difference between only and values is only also fetches the id.

Answer (score 21):

We can select required fields over values.

```
Employee.objects.all().values('eng_name','rank')
```

Comment: After the query is run successfully, how to store the value of a field in a variable, eg. **var_name = <query_name>.<field_name>** ?

Comment: @user12379095 just simply like this: `var_name = Employee.objects.all().values('eng_name','rank')`

Comment: @user12379095 and then to use this var_name - for example: print all the employees names and rank, you can do this: `for person in var_name: print(person['eng_name'] + " " + person['rank'])`

Answer (score 9):

[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) answer is right on the spot. If you want to query more than one field do this:

```
Employee.objects.values_list('eng_name','rank')
```

This will return list of tuples. You cannot use named=Ture when querying more than one field.

Moreover if you know that only one field exists with that info and you know the pk id then do this:

```
Employee.objects.values_list('eng_name','rank').get(pk=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Oskar Persson's answer is the best way to handle it because makes it easier to pass the data to the **context** and treat it normally from the **template** as we get the object instances (easily iterable to get props) instead of a plain value list.

After that you can just easily get the wanted prop:

```
for employee in employees:
    print(employee.eng_name)
```

Or in the template:

```
{% for employee in employees %}

    <p>{{ employee.eng_name }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use values_list alongside filter like so;

```
active_emps_first_name = Employees.objects.filter(active=True).values_list('first_name',flat=True)
```

More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Answer (score 2):

```
Employees.objects.filter().only('eng_name')
```

This will give a QuerySet of all rows, but with only the specified fields. It does NOT give a list like the other answers above. It gives your the OBJECT INSTANCES. Watch out; it is objects.filter().only() NOT just objects.only()

It is similar to SQL Query:

```
SELECT eng_name FROM Employees;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
queryset = ModelName.objects.filter().only('field1', 'field2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list with field names

```
field_names = ['product_id', 'name', 'price', 'status']
results = ModelName.objects.all().values_list(*field_names)

# or for example
# results = ModelName.objects.all().values_list(*field_names, named=True)
```