# Django - select specific columns using Model field properties with only

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to refer to the fields not using strings? I've been looking around at documentation and I only see examples of only() with strings rather than referred to the field properties of the Model object. I try to avoid using 'magic strings' when I can. Is this possible?

For example, looking at the [only documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) and other stack posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115041/7994318) all have the `only()` method with strings as arguments.

Comment: Access using string names is very flexible which is why most people are happy with it. What use case do you see for using field variables as opposed to field names?

Comment: you can always use `YourModel.your_field.field_name` instead of string, but that's the same as using `'your_field'`, so what's the point? Note: `YourModel.pk` has no `field_name` attr, but `YourModel.id` has.

If you are not accessing specific field but instead using some introspection through `YourModel._meta.fields` then you can use `field.attname`: `YourModel.objects.filter(...).only(*[field.attname for field in YourModel._meta.fields if meets_some_condition(field)])`